# Why am i getting error in function addRandomNumbers?

Tags: c

I am getting an error in addRandomNumbers(). Maybe I didn't correctly allocate memory dynamically? I really have no idea what I did wrong.

The error is:

> 'Exception thrown: read access violation. _array was 0x1110112.'

Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void allocateArray(int** _array, int row, int col) {
    _array = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        _array[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * col);
}
void addRandomNumbers(int** _array, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            _array[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}
void print(int** _array, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%d ", _array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main() {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int** _array = NULL;

    allocateArray(_array, 5, 5);
    addRandomNumbers(_array, 5, 5);

    print(_array, 5, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "some error" - what's the error?

Comment: it says: 'Exception thrown: read access violation.
_array was 0x1110112.'

Comment: That's a *crash*, which means you should use a *debugger* to catch it, and locate when and where in your code it happens. When the debugger catches the crash you can also examine the values of involved variables to make sure they're okay and valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `_array` to the `allocateArray` function by value, so any changes to the corresponding parameter aren't reflected in the variable in the `main` function.  This means that `_array` is still NULL when you pass it to `addRandomNumbers`.

Change `allocateArray` to return the allocated pointer:

```
int **allocateArray(int row, int col) {
    int **_array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        _array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * col);
    }
    return _array;
}
```

Then assign the return value back to `_array`:

```
_array = allocateArray(5, 5);
```

Alternately, you can change the parameter type to `int ***` and dereference when using it:

```
void allocateArray(int ***_array, int row, int col) {
    *_array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        (*_array)[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * col);
    }
}
```

And pass the address of the variable in `main`:

```
allocateArray(&_array, 5, 5);
```

Comment: @alex01011 You can also do that: change the parameter type and dereference it when assigning, i.e. `*_array = malloc(...);` and `(*_array)[i] = malloc(...);`

Comment: But i want a function to be void, is it even possible to make it?

Comment: @ig2jmu just look at the comment above, pass a triple star pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running into a segmentation fault because that's the error I receive on my machine by running this code.

I think the issue is with `allocateArray()`, not `addRandomNumbers()`. `addRandomNumbers()` is unable to write to the array because the array was not allocated properly. Try this instead:

```
void allocateArray(int ***_array, int row, int col) {
    *_array = (int **)malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        (*_array)[i] = (int *)malloc(col * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

Likewise, to free the memory, try:

```
void freeArray(int **_array, int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        free(arr[row]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```